# How to connect to a S3 bucket from Redshift across 2 separate accounts using access key and secret key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have 1 AWS account. I have 1 RedShift cluster in that account. There exists an AWS S3 bucket external to this account. I have an access key and a secret key. I am able to list the files in the bucket in the AWS CLI to verify that the key works. What I do not know how to do is supply the access key and the secret key to RedShift when using the 'Load Data' dialogue. I get an access denied error raised.

It seems to me that I will need to create an IAM role that can connect to the bucket using those values and use that role in the dialogue rather than the default role I created. Is this correct, are there alternative approaches?

There are similar questions on this topic, they do not however address my specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. The Redshift cluster can 'assume' the IAM Role and it will be used to access the S3 bucket.

Therefore, you should:

- **Create an IAM Role** in the same AWS Account as the Redshift cluster
- **Add permissions** to the IAM Role to access the S3 bucket in the other account
- Within the other AWS Account, **add a Bucket Policy on the bucket**, granting permission for the above IAM Role to access the bucket

Comment: I don't have any control over the external S3 account. I have to use the keys. I have found that it is possible to specify the keys in a COPY statement.

Answer (score 0):

I can access the file using the COPY command and specifying the keys.

```
COPY XXXXX
FROM 'XXXXX'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=XXXXX;aws_secret_access_key=XXXXX' 
DELIMITER ','
DATEFORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD'
REGION AS 'eu-west-1'
IGNOREHEADER 1
;
```